# How to pass a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a bookmarlet based on this site: http://www.latentmotion.com/how-to-create-a-jquery-bookmarklet/

This is the code of bookmarlet:

```
javascript:(function(){
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')0],
         script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src='http://myserver.com/bookmarlet-remote.js?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
    head.appendChild(script);
})(); 
void 0
```

How I can pass a variable from the bookmarlet (above code), to bookmarlet-remote.js ?

I've tried after var myNewvar='myValue', without success, Any Idea?

Comment: Try creating a variable without using var.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All JS code on a page (including bookmarklet code and scripts included have) have access to the global scope. If you define a variable without the `var` prefix it will be available to all other scripts.

It might be a good idea to be explicit about this. do `window.myVar = "foo";` to clearly signal that you are working with global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using var in the function makes it local to that function. To make it global you have to add it to the scope of the `window`, so:

```
window.newVariable = window.newVariable || 'Your new value here';
```

OR

```
window['newVariable'] = 'Your new value here';
```

Comment: The first option prevents you from overwriting the variable if you've already defined it, the second just adds it to the set of variables available in the global scope.

Comment: You want || not |.  || is OR, | is bitwise OR, which is completely different

Comment: Also, it needs to be `window` not `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a public variable.

```
window.rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
```

In bookmarlet-remote.js you just access the variable.

Comment: drop the `var` here since the code he writes is inside a function body.

Comment: yup... saw my mistake and corrected it before I saw your comment.