# JavaScript Variable Passing between different .js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass 4 variables from one js file to another.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113421/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-javascript) that you must write:

```
window.myVar = "foo";
```

to make your variable "super"-global.

In the first js file, I have

```
window.signJoueur1 = string1.charAt(7);  
window.signJoueur2 = string2.charAt(7);  
window.valeurJoueur1 = random1;  
window.valeurJoueur2 = random2;
```

In the second js file, I did

```
console.log(window.signJoueur1);
console.log(window.signJoueur2);
console.log(window.valeurJoueur1);
console.log(window.valeurJoueur2);

function trouveCombinaison(signJoueur1, signJoueur2, valeurJoueur1, valeurJoueur2)
{
console.log(signJoueur1);
console.log(signJoueur2);
console.log(valeurJoueur1);
console.log(valeurJoueur2);
}
```

It should work, but all console.log return `undefined'.

If you want more informations here are the full codes:
    first .js http://pastebin.com/0zJKFNem
    second .js http://pastebin.com/TsWc7TxL
    the html http://pastebin.com/t3SzwZSC

So, my question is, how can I actually pass through the variables?

Comment: Please don't just add a '2' to the title to allow your question to be posted. Come up with a more meaningful title.

Comment: in trouveCombinaison, it passes as arguments, so that will comes under scope of trouveCombinaison. in that variables has value `undefined`

Comment: @George i took into account your request, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the values before they exist.

The code that assigns the values to the variables are inside a function, and that function isn't called until you click a button. The code that tries to show the values is executed when the page loads, so it uses the variables before they have been assigned any values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i just had to put `window.` in the second console.log group.

Such as :

```
function trouveCombinaison()
{
console.log(window.signJoueur1);
console.log(window.signJoueur2);
console.log(window.valeurJoueur1);
console.log(window.valeurJoueur2);
}
```

The fact that the console.log out of the function don't work is that it's executed when the page loads, as explained by @Guffa.

Now it works.

Comment: Why do you even need arguments to that function? They do nothing.